# Double edge forked forest

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I know how to draw a forked edge in the forest package

```latex
   \begin{forest}
    forked edges,
      [test [ok][doubled[test][fest][boost]]]
   \end{forest}
```

And it gives me this result

[image]

I would like to do double edges in forked tree as done in this screenshot, so only for certain edges
[image]

does someone know how it can be done?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: thanks for the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a macro `\doubleedge[<height>]{<firstnode>}{<secondnode>}` to call just before `\end{forest}`. It requires that you `name` the leftmost and rightmost children below the double bar. The default height is 2mm above the `north` position of `firstnode`, but you can change that with the optional `<height>`. To make sure the doubled edges all look the same, the nodes should all be the same height, so I set `minimum height` to 3.5ex.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}

\newcommand{\doubleedge}[3][2mm]{\draw([yshift=#1]#2.north)--([yshift=#1]#2.north-|#3.north);}

\begin{document}

   \begin{forest}
    for tree={forked edge, draw, anchor=center, minimum height=3.5ex}
      [test[ok, name=j][doubled, name=k[test, name=A1][fest][boost, name=B1]]]  
    \doubleedge{A1}{B1};
    \doubleedge{k}{j};
   \end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked!